# How to make tikz mindmap that where the second node and the first node are connnected horizontally, not vertically

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, every node/.style=concept, concept color=blue, level 1/.append style={level distance=4cm, sibling angle=90}]
\node{apple}
child{node{fruit}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output:
[image]It is unsatisfactory on two front:firstly, the child node is connected to the parent node vertically which takes more space than I would like. Secondly, it is of different sizes. I would like to specify to have two equal size nodes. 
Maybe I shouldn't use mindmap library. So if that is the case, please point to the right library I should use. I am looking for something that have the same nice transformation on the connecting edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the angle e.g. with `clockwise from=0`, and the size e.g. with `every concept/.append style={minimum size=6em,text width=5em}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, every node/.style={concept}, 
every concept/.append style={minimum size=6em,text width=5em},
concept color=blue,clockwise from=0, 
level 1/.append style={level distance=4cm, sibling angle=90}]
\node{apple}
child{node{fruit}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]